# PostSharp warnings when using fakes in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, postsharp, microsoft-fakes

We've updated to VS2012 recently and also changed our PostSharp version to 3.0.26. Generally this combination works fine, but I get warnings for my unit test project such as

*The module "`MyModule.Fakes.dll`" does not contain any aspect or other transformation. For improved build-time performance, consider disabling PostSharp for this module by setting the compilation symbol (aka constant) "SkipPostSharp" in your project or set the MSBuild property "SkipPostSharp=True".*

Now usually I can disable this warning by changing the project settings accordingly (SkipPostSharp = True), but I've already done that for my MyProjectTest project containing the unit tests.

When I add `<SkipPostSharp>True</SkipPostSharp>` to my `MyModule.Fakes` file in the `Fakes` folder, the warning about PostSharp disappears, however, I get another error message:

*The element "Fakes" in namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" has invalid child element "SkipPostSharp" in namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/". List of possible elements expected: "StubGeneration, ShimGeneration, Compilation" in namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011".*

**Update**

I also tried editing the `fakes.xsd` file and add an extra `SkipPostSharp` element, but a) this still isn't recognised as a valid element by Visual Studio and b) I'm not sure whether this would be the right approach anyway.

Any ideas how to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify additional properties for the project file Fakes will generate to build the fakes assembly by placing Property elements inside of the Compilation element at the end of the .FAKES file. Here is an example based on your description.

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="MyModule"/>
  <Compilation>
    <Property Name="SkipPostSharp">True</Property>
  </Compilation>
</Fakes>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. I found out that I have to (as in your code, but I had more elements in my file) put the `Compilation` element at the end of the file.